# How can I change only one letter of .mp3 in python?

Tags: python

So I have to change the letter "ı" because it is not an english character for example I should change "sanmayın.mp3" to "sanmayin.mp3". How can I do this?

```
from os import rename, listdir

fnames = listdir('.')


for fname in fnames:
    print fname
    fname.replace('ý','i')
```

Okay I got why it didn't work listdir gives all of the names in english so python thinks that ı is i, how can I get it to work in UTF-8

Comment: Hey! You may want to look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Would you like to include a code sample of what you already tried?

Comment: Sorry, added the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace()`:

```
s = 'sanmayın.mp3'
s.replace('ı','i')
```

**Result**:

```
sanmayin.mp3
```

If you needed to replace characters within a list:

```
l = ['sanmayın.mp3', 'ın', 'hı']
l = [i.replace('ı','i') for i in l]
```

**Result**:

```
['sanmayin.mp3', 'in', 'hi']
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, the thing is I should change every single ı in an mp3 folder, so I use 

`from os import rename, listdir

fnames = listdir('.')

fnames.replace('ý','i')` But since this is a list replace won't work

Comment: `str.replace` can be used on any string you need to replace characters, so that's entirely up to you.

Comment: Can I use it in list too?

Comment: Yes, you would do `l = [i.replace('ı','i') for i in l]` or similar... where `l` is the list

Comment: I understood the problem, it is because of the listdir, it gets ı as i so python  doesn't find any "ı"s.